# Song Cycle Texts, all at the beginning or placed individually before each song?

Tags: notation, composition, sheet-music

Following the recommendation that the text for a song be provided separately as part of the front matter of a vocal composition, what is the best way to handle the texts for a song cycle if each text is an individual poem? Should all the texts be placed at the beginning of the song cycle, or should each text be placed before the song in which it is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all the poems together in the front matter.
This lets someone who's investigating the text independently of the music
do so for all the poems together, instead of having to leaf back and forth.

Placing each poem before its song would be *slightly* more convenient for someone who's interested in only one song of the cycle.

Comment: Excellent insight.